# How to get rank student using laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to get the rank of the student using the total marks, i.e. the student with higher marks than the other should be first and so on. Then when two or more students have the same total marks, they should have the same rank, help me.
I have two tables.

1- table - students:

```
id  name    class_id created_at
1   Emma     1    
2   Frank    3    
3   Bright   4    
4   Mark     1
```

2- table - marks:

```
id id_student  class_id  subject_id  mark   created_at
1   2           3         2          115 
2   4           1         1          120
3   3           4         4          90
```

I want to get the rank for student the highly mark. How to make it please.

Comment: Have you make 2 model? and connect them using 1 to one? from marks... The query should be `select s.name,m.mark from marks as m, students as s where m.id_student = s.id and m.class_id = s.class_id and subject_id = <some subject id>`, if you need it on different subject...

Comment: Thank to reply me, so could you give me a clean code because it's a long time since I'm blocked it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$count = Marks::count(); 

$Marks= Marks::orderBy('mark', 'DESC')->get()->groupBy('mark')->take($count);
            $no = 1;
            foreach ($Marks as $key => $student) {
                foreach ($student as $new => $s) {
                    $stu = Student::where('id', $s->id_student)->first();
                    $stu->rank = "Rank " . $no;
                    $stu->save();
                }
                $no++;
            }
```

after fetching $marks dd($marks) see the structure then decide one foreach loop is sufficient or two needed

It will work...